# How to convert equations into closed forms

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have questions about this equation. 
[image]

How could I convert this equation into closed form?

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate $f_0,f_1,f_2,f_3$, and $f_4$, you should be able to make a conjecture as to a closed form for $f_n$ that you can then try to prove by induction on $n$.

Alternatively, you could try to interpret $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k(n-k)^n(-1)^k$ as an application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count something; there is a very simple closed form for what it counts.

Comment: As a further hint, think of bijections from $[n]$ to $[n]$ as functions $f$ from $[n]$ to $[n]$ that have none of the $n$ properties that $j$ is not in the image of $f$, where $j\in [n]$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the following lemma to solve your question.

> **Lemma.** For $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, let
>   $$f_{n,k}:=\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}j^k.$$
>   Then
>   $$f_{n,k}=
> \begin{cases}
> 0& 0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\\
> n!& k=n
> \end{cases}.$$

*Proof of Lemma.* A glance at
$$e^x-1=x+o(x),\ x\to 0$$
can get
$$\left(e^x-1\right)^n=x^n+o\left(x^n\right).$$
This yields
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}e^{jx}=x^n+o\left(x^n\right).$$
Taking the derivative repeatedly, we obtain
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}j^k e^{jx}=A_n^k x^{n-k}+o\left(x^{n-k}\right).$$
Putting $x=0$, it follows that
$$f_{n,k}=
\begin{cases}
0& 0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1\\
n!& k=n
\end{cases}.\quad\square$$
Now we shift our attention to $f_n$ :
\begin{align*}
f_n& =\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-1\right)^j\binom{n}{n-j}\left(n-j\right)^k\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-1\right)^{n-j}\binom{n}{j}j^k=f_{n,n}=\color{blue}{n!}
\end{align*}